# A Novi is the spokesperson of G-d

Tags: sources-mekorot, navi-prophets, nevua-prophecy

I read in [*Jewish Wisdom in the Numbers*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422613443.html) on page 291, the following:

*The primary function of a* נביא, ***prophet***, was to serve as the spokesperson of G-d. This title, derived from the phrase נִיב שְֹפָתָיִם, ***fruits of the lips***, depicted a prophet as the mouthpiece publicly broadcasting the word of G-d.

Does anyone know where the source for this can be found?

Comment: See [Rashi on N'chemya 6:7](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A2:%D7%A8%D7%A9%22%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%95_%D7%96): "נביאים - בעלי לשון כמו בורא ניב שפתים".

Comment: Clarification, please. WHICH source? That a Navi is a spokesperson for G-d or that the word "Navi" comes from  נִיב שְֹפָתָיִם?

Answer (score 1):

@Fred has provided the source for the "fruit of the lips" concept. I'll leave the task for him to expand upon it, if needed.

The proof that a prophet was G-d's "mouthpiece" is in this week's Torah reading.

Deuteronomy 18:18:

> נָבִ֨יא אָקִ֥ים לָהֶ֛ם מִקֶּ֥רֶב אֲחֵיהֶ֖ם כָּמ֑וֹךָ וְנָתַתִּ֤י
>   דְבָרַי֙ בְּפִ֔יו וְדִבֶּ֣ר אֲלֵיהֶ֔ם אֵ֖ת כָּל־אֲשֶׁ֥ר אֲצַוֶּֽנּוּ׃
>
> I will establish a prophet from among their brothers, like you; and I
>   will put My words in his mouth, and he shall speak to them all that I
>   shall command him.